# nodejs Twit posting a random youtube link

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a working bot with the retweet function on posts with hashtags.

Using Nodejs and twit

Now Im trying to create a youtube link generator but seem to be sending myself in circles.

Any help with this would be appreciated..

```
const Twit = require('twit')
const config = require('./config')
var Twitter = new Twit(config)
require('console-stamp')(console, '[HH:MM:ss.l]');
console.log('the bot is looking at bot.js');

let phraseArray = [
  "Rod Stewart - If you think Im sexy https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hphwfq1wLJs",
  "Tom Jones - Not Unusual - Live Tea in the park https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zydIvSDXS7Y",
  "Britney Spears - Baby one more time - Live in hawaii https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5vjFljmxecY"

];
function chooseRandom(array) {
  return array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
}
let phrase =
  chooseRandom(phraseArray);
Twitter.post('statuses/update', { status: chooseRandom });

chooseRandom();

setInterval(chooseRandom, 60*60*1000);
console.log('read through bot.js');
```

Comment: can you please give more context on what you are trying to achieve. Like what you tried and what you have seen and whats the expected output

Comment: yep..  basically just to post a description and youtube link direct to twitter. I have tried all sorts of searches but many seem to be to post an image with text etc but can't seem to find any help on google for posting a random link.

Comment: Just to add I started the 100daysofcode challenge about a fortnight ago so im very new to this..  I just found adding the retweet bot fun so thought Id try this as my next project. The code above may be completely wrong for the task so I do apologise if it is..  But I am a noob and prepared to learn.

Comment: ok twitter.post is an async operation so you should either use callback or promises to make sure whether the operation was successful or not
`Twitter.post('statuses/update', { status: 'hello world!' }, function(err, data, response) {
  console.log(data)
})`
what are you trying to post is `phrase`, `chooseRandom` is a function in your case I think status should be string and you are trying to post a function without it being evaluated

Comment: if you are new then you need to learn about callbacks/async operations https://medium.com/codebuddies/getting-to-know-asynchronous-javascript-callbacks-promises-and-async-await-17e0673281ee
https://scotch.io/courses/10-need-to-know-javascript-concepts/callbacks-promises-and-async

Comment: Thats great. Im not after handouts so help on where to look and learn is great..  I shall go and have a right old read and play and see what happens in the next few days..  Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

I followed your code to tweet random phrases and it worked, but they have to be in the array.

```
let phrases= [""]; //this is your array

function tweetIt() {

var posts= phrases[Math.floor(Math.random() * phrases.length)];

let tweet = { status: posts
}
```